# DLP instances for given number of congruences

Tags: discrete-logarithm, terminology, security-definition, literature

Let $S$ be the set of $k$ congruences of the type $g_{i}^{x_i} \equiv h_i \pmod{n_i}, \quad \forall i,1\leq i \leq k$

What would be the best way to describe such set $S$ with a term in literature. The goal is that the reader immediately thinks about this set of congruences when reading the term.

Would it be a collection or set of DLP instances a valid reference?

Comment: As I always say: you are free to downvote, but please comment out what problems do you find with my question so I can clarify

Comment: Please always try to make your title as specific as possible (not the downvoter)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What would be the best way to describe such system of $k$ congruences with a term so I can reference to it in literature. The goal is that the reader immediately thinks about this system when reading the term.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be the person that answers either. If you have any additions to the question then please edit them in rather than to comment; my inbox is full enough as it is.